# Publish MongoDB in Windows Azure worker role - Always Busy

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure, cloud, azure-worker-roles

I have developed my application with mongoDB and now I'm ready to live in cloud.

I have followed the tutorial from official mongoDB website about how to deploy it in 
windows azure's worker role.

I have tried with local deployment in windows azure emulator, everything work really fine.

But when I tried to publish it into cloud service, the result wasn't like my expectation.

**MongoDB.WindowsAzure.MongoDBRole_IN_X** (where X is the instance number) is always in busy status with message ..

> Starting role...
>   UnhandledException:Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudDriveException

I have no clue about this.

Could anyone have any suggestion ?

Thx.

PS1. Sorry for my english.

PS2. I have used the latest version of windows azure SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that worker role setup, MongoDb sets itself up to store the database on a *durable drive* (basically a vhd mounted in a blob). Since you're getting a `CloudDriveException`, the first thing I'd look at is the storage connection string for the account being used for mounting drives. Could it be that your configuration file is still pointing at local dev storage?

Comment: David, @ping_smiley, would you please mind being a little more specific in the details? I'm also getting this exact problem now and haven't been able to find any more detailed resources on exactly where to fix this and what to change it to. Is it the MongoDBDataDir?

Comment: Update: Setting up my own Azure storage, then pointing to it from the worker role's MongoDBDataDir setting with account name and key still brings up the same error message by OP.